# jQuery/ASMX: Error Deserializing JSON in C#

Tags: c#, jquery, json, ajax, web-services

I'm doing an AJAX POST against a C# ASMX web method and I cannot get the JSON data to deserialize.  This should work, but is giving me the following error...

```
{"Message":"Cannot convert object of type \u0027System.String\u0027 to type \u0027System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary`2[System.String,System.Object]\u0027","StackTrace":" at System.Web.Script.Serialization.ObjectConverter.ConvertObjectToTypeInternal(Object o, Type type, JavaScriptSerializer serializer, Boolean throwOnError, Object\u0026 convertedObject)\r\n at System.Web.Script.Serialization.ObjectConverter.ConvertObjectToTypeMain(Object o, Type type, JavaScriptSerializer serializer, Boolean throwOnError, Object\u0026 convertedObject)\r\n at System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.Deserialize[T](String input)\r\n at System.Web.Script.Services.RestHandler.ExecuteWebServiceCall(HttpContext context, WebServiceMethodData methodData)","ExceptionType":"System.InvalidOperationException"}
```

Here is the WebMethod...

```
    [WebMethod]
    [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
    public void SaveProfileProperties(string data)
    {
        ups.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
        try
        {
            System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"E:\Log.txt", data);
        }
        catch { }

        var json = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        Dictionary<string, string> props = json.Deserialize<Dictionary<string, string>>(data);
        SaveSQLData(props);
    }
```

Here is the data that is being sent...

```
"{data:{\"userName\":\"Doe\",\"UserProfile_GUID\":\"\",\"AccountName\":\"Domain\\Doe\",\"FirstName\":\"John\",\"LastName\":\"Doe\",\"PreferredName\":\"John Doe\",\"WorkPhone\":\"2176\",\"Department\":\"PHI\",\"Title\":\"Director\",\"SPS-JobTitle\":\"Director\",\"Manager\":\"Domain\\jdoe\",\"PersonalSpace\":\"/my/personal/Doe/\",\"PictureURL\":\"Doe_MThumb.jpg\",\"UserName\":\"Doe\",\"SPS-ClaimProviderID\":\"Windows\",\"SPS-ClaimProviderType\":\"Windows\",\"SPS-SavedAccountName\":\"Domain\\Doe\",\"SPS-DistinguishedName\":\"CN=John Doe,CN=Users,DC=domain,DC=local\",\"SPS-LastKeywordAdded\":\"1/2/2014 12:00:00 AM\",\"WorkEmail\":\"Doe@domain.com\",\"CellPhone\":\"5555555555\",\"Office\":\"C28\",\"SPS-TimeZone\":\"WF_Service.UPS.SPTimeZone\",\"personalEmail\":\"Doe.John@gmail.com\",\"SPS-EmailOptin\":\"0\",\"empID\":\"224\",\"team\":\"A\",\"p_id\":\"224\",\"username\":\"Doe\",\"last_name\":\"Doe\",\"first_name\":\"John\",\"birthday\":\"1/2/1985 12:00:00 AM\",\"anniv\":\"6/4/2007 12:00:00 AM\",\"imageurl\":\"A0BB.jpg\",\"Position\":\"Director\",\"dept_started_in\":\"IT\",\"birthplace\":\"NC\",\"marital_status\":\"Married\",\"sports_team\":\"Sporty Sports\",\"last_school\":\"None\",\"hobbies\":\"\",\"pets\":\"\",\"prior_employer\":\"None\",\"resides_in\":\"USA\",\"quote\":\"“Where you live should not determine whether you live, or whether you die.”  -- Bono\",\"fav_color\":\"009933\"}}"
```

**Update:** This is Client Side.  After some testing I figured out that the stack trace error at the beginning of my post is actually client side.

**Update 2:** Turns out that the JSON serialization was failing on the client side.  Here is the correct way to prepare the data...

```
json.Stringify({data:{\"userName\":\"Doe\",\"UserProfile_GUID\":\"\",\"AccountName\":\"Domain\\Doe\",\"FirstName\":\"John\",\"LastName\":\"Doe\",\"PreferredName\":\"John Doe\",\"WorkPhone\":\"2176\",\"Department\":\"PHI\",\"Title\":\"Director\",\"SPS-JobTitle\":\"Director\",\"Manager\":\"Domain\\jdoe\",\"PersonalSpace\":\"/my/personal/Doe/\",\"PictureURL\":\"Doe_MThumb.jpg\",\"UserName\":\"Doe\",\"SPS-ClaimProviderID\":\"Windows\",\"SPS-ClaimProviderType\":\"Windows\",\"SPS-SavedAccountName\":\"Domain\\Doe\",\"SPS-DistinguishedName\":\"CN=John Doe,CN=Users,DC=domain,DC=local\",\"SPS-LastKeywordAdded\":\"1/2/2014 12:00:00 AM\",\"WorkEmail\":\"Doe@domain.com\",\"CellPhone\":\"5555555555\",\"Office\":\"C28\",\"SPS-TimeZone\":\"WF_Service.UPS.SPTimeZone\",\"personalEmail\":\"Doe.John@gmail.com\",\"SPS-EmailOptin\":\"0\",\"empID\":\"224\",\"team\":\"A\",\"p_id\":\"224\",\"username\":\"Doe\",\"last_name\":\"Doe\",\"first_name\":\"John\",\"birthday\":\"1/2/1985 12:00:00 AM\",\"anniv\":\"6/4/2007 12:00:00 AM\",\"imageurl\":\"A0BB.jpg\",\"Position\":\"Director\",\"dept_started_in\":\"IT\",\"birthplace\":\"NC\",\"marital_status\":\"Married\",\"sports_team\":\"Sporty Sports\",\"last_school\":\"None\",\"hobbies\":\"\",\"pets\":\"\",\"prior_employer\":\"None\",\"resides_in\":\"USA\",\"quote\":\"“Where you live should not determine whether you live, or whether you die.”  -- Bono\",\"fav_color\":\"009933\"}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try methods in below link

http://procbits.com/2011/04/21/quick-json-serializationdeserialization-in-c

Comment: I tried using Dictionary<string, dynamic> and I get the same error.